# Perl IO::Socket::INET

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; use strict;

use IO::Socket::INET;

our $local_host = "0.0.0.0";
our $local_port = "14267";


$SIG{'CHLD'} = 'IGNORE';
my $bind = IO::Socket::INET->new(
                        Listen=>5,
                        LocalAddr=>$local_host.':'.$local_port,
                        ReuseAddr=>1) 
                        or die print('Could not bind: ' .$local_host.':'.$local_port);
```

When I try to execute this code from terminal it works, but when I try to execute it from browser it return could not bind etc.

Someone can explain to me what the problem is? It is not about user privileges I think.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this to do? What do you mean by "it works" in the terminal? How are you calling this from your browser?

Comment: $ perl test.pl from terminal it works. from browser i try to execute it through php function like exec() shell_exec() syste().

Comment: "could not bind etc etc...." - `$!` (i.e. `$ERRNO`) should contain more details about the problem. Please add it to your code and the output to your question.

Answer (score 3):

How could you possibly know it couldn't bind? You always log "Could not bind" no matter what error occurred! More importantly, you don't log what error occurred! The first step would be to correct that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; use strict;

use IO::Socket::INET;

my $local_port = 14267;

my $server_socket = IO::Socket::INET->new(
   LocalPort => $local_port,
   Listen    => 5,
   ReuseAddr => 1,
)
   or die("Can't create server socket: $@");    # <-- The relevant change.
```

I suspect you'll get some kind of permission error because of a security framework like SElinux.

Comment: For the curious, `$@` (usually used for the error message from the last `eval`) is not a typo; that's where modules in the IO::* family generally report errors. It's confusing, but [would be difficult to change at this point](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=120764).

Comment: I solved, thank you, as i logged errors, i have permission problems.

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell if it's SELinux or something else. If it is SELinux, there are ways of telling it to allow your socket creation. Googling should find this pretty easily.